# Как в Retrofit отправлять запросы через определенный период времени?

Tags: android, retrofit, rxjava

Использую `Retrofit` и `RxJava`, как в Retrofit отправлять запросы на сервер, например, раз в 5 минут?

мой Api класс:

```
public class BaseApi {
    private static BaseApi instance = null;
    public static CryptoApi service;
    private static OkHttpClient client;
    private static Retrofit retrofit;


        public BaseApi() {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor logger = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            logger.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .addInterceptor(logger)
                    .build();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            service = retrofit.create(CryptoApi.class);
        }

        public static BaseApi getInstance() {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new BaseApi();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

public interface CryptoApi {

        @GET("?limit=5")
        Observable<List<Crypto>> getCrypto();

    }
```

Метод, в котором делаю запрос на сервер:

```
private void getCrypto() {
        Subscription subscription = BaseApi.getInstance().service.getCrypto()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(crypto -> {
                   Log.d("Crypto", crypto.toString())
                }, throwable -> {
                    Log.e("User from server error", String.valueOf(throwable));
                });
        addSubscription(subscription);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно 2 способами:

1. Использовать оператор `repeatWhen` [так](http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/):

```
private void getCrypto() {
    Subscription subscription = BaseApi.getInstance().service.getCrypto()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .repeatWhen(completed -> completed.delay(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) 
            .subscribe(crypto -> {
               Log.d("Crypto", crypto.toString())
            }, throwable -> {
                Log.e("User from server error", String.valueOf(throwable));
            });
    addSubscription(subscription);
}
```

2. Использовать `AlarmManager` для постоянного выстрела `Intent`-ами, которые будет принимать `BroadcastReceiver` и запускать единожды ваш метод.

---

Первый способ позволит в одну строку сделать, а второй позволит повторять запуск метода даже после закрытия приложения и (при совмещении с реакцией на событие запуска девайса) перезагрузки девайса, независимо от жизненного цикла приложения.

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает!